# Unable to login to a site with requests

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests

For fun, I'm trying to use Python requests to log on to my school's student portal. This is what I've come up with so far. I'm trying to be very explicit on the headers, because I'm getting a 200 status code (the code you also get when failing to login) instead of a 302 (successful login).

```
import sys
import os
import requests

def login(username, password):
    url = '(link)/home.html#sign-in-content'
    values = {
        'translator_username' : '',
        'translator_password' : '',
        'translator_ldappassword' : '',
        'returnUrl' : '',
        'serviceName' : 'PS Parent Portal',
        'serviceTicket' : '',
        'pcasServerUrl' : '\/',
        'credentialType' : 'User Id and Password Credential',
        'account' : username,
        'pw' : password,
        'translatorpw' : password
    }

    headers = {
        'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control' : 'max-age=0',
        'connection' : 'keep-alive',
        'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'host' : '(link)',
        'origin' : '(link)',
        'referer' : '(link)guardian/home.html',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests' : '1'
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post(url, data=values)
        if p.status_code == 302:
            print(p.text)
        print('Authentication error', p.status_code)

        r = s.get('(link)guardian/home.html')
        print(r.text)

def main():
    login('myname', 'mypass')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using Chrome to examine the network requests, all of these headers are under 'Request Headers' in addition to a long cookie number, content-length, and user-agent.

The forms are as follows:

```
pstoken:(token)
contextData:(text)
translator_username:
translator_password:
translator_ldappassword:
returnUrl:(url)guardian/home.html
serviceName:PS Parent Portal
serviceTicket:
pcasServerUrl:\/
credentialType:User Id and Password Credential
account:f
pw:(id)
translatorpw:
```

Am I missing something with the headers/form names? Is it a problem with cookies?

If I look at p.requests.headers, this is what is sent:

```
{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'host': '(url)', 'origin': '(url)', 'referer': '(url)guardian/home.html', 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', 'Content-Length': '263'}
```

p.text gives me the HTML of the login page

Tested with PowerAPI, requests, Mechanize, and RoboBrowser. All fail.

Comment: Give us an example of your request and its response.

Comment: @Sraw Refer to the bottom of the post that I've modified.

Comment: If it helps this is a PowerSchool login form

Answer (score 0):

What response do you expect? You are using a wrong way to analyze your response.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=values)
    if p.status_code == 302:
        print(p.text)
    print('Authentication error', p.status_code)

    r = s.get('(link)guardian/home.html')
    print(r.text)
```

In your code, you print out `Authentication error` ignoring `status_code`, I think it at least should like this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=values)
    if p.status_code == 302:
        print(p.text)
        r = s.get('(link)guardian/home.html')
        print(r.text)
    else:
        print('Authentication error', p.status_code)
```

Comment: Nonetheless, I still get the exact same response and the code is 200.

Comment: @Chase Did you really set your headers? `s.post(url, headers=headers, data=values)`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to set them so I did it and there was no difference. I'm currently trying Robobrowser. The code doesn't yield any errors when the information is submit, but then I go to open a page past the authentication and if I fetch the HTML I can see that it's still the login.